# Change the color attribute of a product

Tags: php, magento-1.9

On each product's page right now there is a drop down menu that shows all colors available for the product. Even if there is only one color available, the drop down list appears. I want this list not be appaearing if the is only on color available. How can I do this ?

Comment: Nothing really. I'm really really new to Magento and I don't know there to start actually   :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion. Unless you are creating a configurable product, you should either use an attribute that is not dropdown type, or simply include the color as part of the product title.